# Проблема с функцией, NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу программу для решения некой биологической задачи, и есть там функция translate, которая транслирует РНК в белок (фактически, для трех букв строки РНК функция выдает один символ, который обозначает аминокислоту). То есть, если у нас есть строка РНК "AUGCCG", то функция должна возвращать "MP", потому что триплет AUG соответствует аминокислоте метионин (M), а CCG - аминокислоте пролин (Р).

Теперь сам код. Я знаю, что надо было кодировать значения через dictionaries, но... по некоторым причинам получилось так, как получилось :)

```
def translate(rna) :
prot = ''
for i in range(0, len(rna), 3):
    if a[i:i+3] == 'UAA' or a[i:i+3] == 'UAG' or a[i:i+3] == 'UGA' :
        break
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'UUU' or a[i:i+3] == 'UUC' :
        prot += 'F'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'UUA' or a[i:i+3] == 'UUG' :
        prot += 'L'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'UC' or a[i:i+3] == 'AGU' or a[i:i+3] == 'AGC' :
        prot += 'S'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'UA' :
        prot += 'Y'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'UGU' or a[i:i+3] == 'UGC' :
        prot += 'C'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'UGG' :
        prot += 'W'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'CU' :
        prot += 'L'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'CC' :
        prot += 'P'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'CAU' or a[i:i+3] == 'CAC' :
        prot += 'H'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'CAA' or a[i:i+3] == 'CAG' :
        prot += 'Q'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'CG' or a[i:i+3] == 'AGA' or a[i:i+3] == 'AGG' :
        prot += 'R'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'AUG' :
        prot += 'M'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'AUU' or a[i:i+3] == 'AUC' or a[i:i+3] == 'AUA' :
        prot += 'I'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'AC' :
        prot += 'T'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'AAU' or a[i:i+3] == 'AAC' :
        prot += 'N'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'AAA' or a[i:i+3] == 'AAG' :
        prot += 'K'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'GU' :
        prot += 'V'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'GC' :
        prot += 'A'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'GAU' or a[i:i+3] == 'GAC' :
        prot += 'D'
    elif a[i:i+3] == 'GAA' or a[i:i+3] == 'GAG' :
        prot += 'E'
    elif a[i:i+2] == 'GG' :
        prot += 'G'
return prot

string = 'AUGGUCUACAUAGCUGACAAACAGCACGUAGCAUCUCGAGAGGCAUAUGGUCACAUGUUCAAAGUUUGCGCCUAG'
prot = translate(string)
```

Когда пытаюсь запустить, на последней строке кода выдает ошибку : "NameError: name 'a' is not defined".

Причем, что самое интересное, если изменить просто имя переменной со "string" на "а", вот так:

```
a = 'AUGGUCUACAUAGCUGACAAACAGCACGUAGCAUCUCGAGAGGCAUAUGGUCACAUGUUCAAAGUUUGCGCCUAG'
prot = translate(a)
```

то всё работает, выдает правильный ответ ("MVYIADKQHVASREAYGHMFKVCA")

Почему ошибка возникает? Наверное, я упустила что-то глупое и легкое, но не понимаю, что. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы внутри функции `translate` обращаетесь к некоторой переменной `a`:

```
if a[i:i+3] == 'UAA'
```

, которую никаким образом туда не передаёте и внутри не вычисляете. (Может быть вы хотите внутри функции все `а` заменить на `rna`?).
Если же переменную вне функции вы называете `a`, то она оказывается в глобальной области видимости. После этого вы внутри функции обращаетесь к этой глобальной переменной и всё действительно работает.
Но стоит внутри функции использовать то, что вы туда передаёте, а не глобальные переменные.